# php preg_replace between two needles

Tags: php, preg-replace

I know this type of question has been asked and answered before but I cant isolate the error in my pattern match.

due to some very screwy legacy db input I am trying to remove anything between two html special chars and then will move on to process the remains after.
the original code went `1<b>2` to bold anything after 1, but has ended up as `1&lt;b&gt;2`

I would like to be left with either `1&lt;&gt;2` or `1 2`

am I even close?

thx
Art

```
$str = '1&lt;b&gt;2';
$output = preg_replace('/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};(.*?)\/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/is', '',$str);
```

Comment: What is wrong with preg_replace('/&lt;[^&]+&gt;/', ' ', $str); ?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey the html special chrs could be anything, so the above is just an example. Based on your working example I tried '/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};[^&]+/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/', replacing the &lt; with a wildcard, but that fails the match process.

Comment: sorry, didn't realise it was any entity.  BTW why the slash in the middle?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey why the slash in the middle? doh-ness!! that was the problem. if you give your above as an answer I will mark it as correct. thx Art

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should remove the slash in the middle

```
/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};[^&]+&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/is
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do:

```
$str = strip_tags(html_entity_decode('1&lt;b&gt;2'));
```

or if you want to replaces tags with something else, like an space:

```
$str = html_entity_decode('1&lt;b&gt;2');
$output = preg_replace('/<\/?[^\>]+>/ui', ' ',$str);
```

Comment: pls see above, it needs to be a wild card as any &... could be in the system. It turns out was an extra / in the regex match. thx Art